# QC OTAClient dll

Tags: hp-quality-center

We have developed a QC Adapter for one of the clients using OTA API by referencing OTACLient.dll

Is this DLL redistributable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TDAPIOLELib.dll` can be generated using `TlbImp.exe OTAClient.dll` (with the correct paths), so IMHO any redistribution concerns should be about `OTAClient.dll`.

OTOH `OTAClient.dll` it's part of the **HP ALM Client Registration** (from the add-in page), so it might ease the deployment:

- Deploys and registers ALM components on a client machine.

Of course, I expect that `OTAClient.dll` and any other client components are legal to use only for licensed clients of HP ALM - still searching on this topic and about the licence count influence of the custom apps using this dll.

Answer (score 0):

I have never read the EULA provided with OTA API, and this is my own personal opinion; but as a hunch I would say it is not supposed to be a problem.
As long as you distribute only your own binaries and non of those owned by HP.

Comment: Hi Alex,
Thanks for your reply,
Well adding a reference to OTAClient.dll for OTA API does a com reference Interop.TDAPIOLELib.dll which gets copied in the bin\Debug or Release folder.  This com ref is vital for the app to work, and have to include it in the package.  So my question again is can i include the interop with the package?

Comment: I think that this is not supposed to be a problem since you are the one creating this file.